# Running external application with Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

A java code needs to control an external application: launch the application, wait the application to finish and read the results obtained (written inside a text file).
I have tried with ProcessBuilder:

```
public class ExecuteNastran {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        command.add("C:\\MSC.Software\\MSC.Nastran\\bin\\nastranw.exe");
        command.add("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\BRUTE-FORCE\\FLAP-TEST-SOL101-TEST-CORRELATION.bdf");
        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            builder.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\BRUTE-FORCE\\"));
            Process p = builder.start();
            p.waitFor(); //Returns inmediatly
            //Process the results which is a text file
        }
        catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

The API doc for the waitFor method says:

*

> public abstract int waitFor() throws InterruptedException Causes the
>   current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by
>   this Process object has terminated. This method returns immediately if
>   the subprocess has already terminated. If the subprocess has not yet
>   terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess
>   exits. Returns:the exit value of the subprocess represented by this
>   Process object. By convention, the value 0 indicates normal
>   termination.

*

The problem is that the process p returns 0  (normal termination) inmediaty, while the extrenal application (MSC Nastran in this case) is still running.

The solution shown in https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2 is about reading streams from external processes but my intention is to read a file generated after the external process has finished.

Comment: When you run "MSC Nastran" from the command line, does it wait or does it complete immediately and return 0 after spawning its' own threads? I would guess the latter. In which case, you will need some other notification mechanism.

Comment: Like @ElliottFrisch states, I also think, that invoking the "MSC Nastran" programm just starts another process and terminates immediately. There is no chance to get notified when this process is terminated. Maybe you could keep watching on the file you are demanding and continue your execution when it exists.

Comment: Plan A. [Watching a Directory for Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) - Plan B. Check the "MSC Nastran" documentation, maybe there's an API. I've never used it myself.

Comment: Invoking MSC Nastran from command line does not close this comand line which remains open. On the other hand, other process is launched appart which is the Nastran process. This process is closed after the application ends. I will check the output directory/output files to be closed by Nastran and read the results as you all suggested